# Please analyze my game

Tags: learning

Here is a recent game I played and I know it is bad, but wanted some input on ways to improve.

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 e5 2.f4 Nc6 3.Nf3 d6 4.d4 Bg4 5.h3 Bxf3 6.Qxf3 Nf6 7.Bc4 Qd7 8.f5 Nxd4 9.Qd3 b5 10.Bb3 h5 11.c4 Rb8 12.Nc3 b4 13.Nb5 Rb7 14.a4 g6 15.O-O Bh6 16.Qd1 gxf5 17.Rxf5 Nxf5 18.exf5 a6 19.Bxh6 Rxh6 20.Qc1 axb5 21.Qxh6 Qxf5 22.Qh8+ Ke7 23.c5 dxc5
```

I resigned, but I find it difficult to see where the worst moves were.

Comment: Were you playing White or Black? If you were White, your biggest mistake was resigning at the end, when you were winning for the first time in the game. Instead of resigning you should have gone on the attack with 24.Rd1 (threatening Qd8 mate) forcing 24...Ne8 or 24...Nd7, and then 25.Rf1 and 26,Rxf7+.

Answer (score 2):

Before I answer I'm sorry if my english is bad. This game opening using King's Gambit declined (C30). I make the assumption that you are aggressive player who like open game than close game based on your opening and moves. In my opinion the several your mistakes and blunders is:

- 5.h3; the best move is 5.d5. Why d5? Because you can push your opponent knight and you winning the center position. If your opponent play 5...Nd4, you can counter with 6. Be3 Nxf3+ 7.gxf3 exf4 8.Bxf4 Bd7 9.Nc3.... You absolutely win the center and have a pole position to develop your pawns and pieces
- 7.Bc4; Black move in 6...Nf6 is mistake, 6...Nd4 is better than 6...Nf6 because he can push your Queen. But you counter with Bc4, the move that you should take is 7.Bb5 because you can freeze your opponent knight. If your opponent moves is 7...exd4, you can counter with 8.0-0 and makes your opponent pawn hanging in the center
- 8.f5, Black move in 7.Qd7 is bad, but your counter move 8.f5 is bad too, you can counter with 8.d5. You will lost your pawn in the center if you take the other move than 8.d5
- 11.c4, In my opinion, black move in 10...h5 is not good. I don't know what his plans but he should take 10...c5 to backup the knight in d4 and can push your Queen and Bishop. Your move should 11.0-0 make your King safer than before. But Black made a mistakw again with 11...Rb8. He should take your pawn in c4 and next move maybe 12.Qxc4 d5 13.exd5. He make your f5 pawn hanging.
- 13.Nb5. It makes your bishop in b3 taken by Black knight
- 14.a4. Maybe it's your biggest mistake in this game. Your opponent 13...Rb7 is bad move. You can obtain his knight in d4 with your knight and next move is 14...exd4 15.Qxd4. You got his pawn in center!!!!
- 15.0-0. Black second biggest mistake is 14...g6??? He can focus in his right side(A-D) and push your pawn. The best Black move is 14...Nxb3. Your counter is  very bad. You should still take the 15.Nxd4 move.
- 16.Qd1. And this is your biggest mistake too. You are lead the game if you take 16.Nxd4 move. 3 move and maybe you still don't realize this is your greatest move so far in this game
- 17.Rxf5. Another biggest mistake too. 4 move and still don't realize.
- 20.Qc1. 20.Qf3 is better
- 22.Qh8+. 22.Rf1 is better
- 23.c5. 23.cxb5 is better

This is my analyze. I'm sorry if I made a mistake too in this analyze

Comment: You should break up your analysis into paragraphs, the wall of text is difficult to read. Also,  your recommendation of d4 at move 5 is impossible, as it was played at move 4.

Answer (score 1):

These are my first thoughts, without the aid of a computer:

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 e5 2.f4 Nc6 3.Nf3 d6 4.d4 Bg4 5.h3 {5.h3 is a wasted move. Putting the question to the bishop doesn't make sense, as Black wins a pawn by removing a defender: 5. h3? Bxf3 6.Qxf3 Nxd4} Bxf3 6.Qxf3 Nf6 7.Bc4 Qd7 8.f5 {8.f5 takes the tension off the pawn centre and closes the f-file, which negates the point for White's play in the King's gambit, i.e. to play against the f7-square, for example with a rook on f1.} Nxd4 9.Qd3 b5 10.Bb3 h5 11.c4 Rb8 12.Nc3 b4 13.Nb5 Rb7 14.a4 {Why not retain the 2-bishops and regains a pawn with 14. Nxd4 exd4 15. Qxd4?} g6 15.O-O Bh6 16.Qd1 gxf5 17.Rxf5 {17.Rxf5 simply loses the exchange for no compensation.} Nxf5 18.exf5 a6 19.Bxh6 Rxh6 20.Qc1 axb5 21.Qxh6 Qxf5 22.Qh8+ {This check doesn't lead anywhere a the queen is not supported. I would have played 22. cxb5 followed by Rf1, placing pressure on f7, f6 and f5.} Ke7 23.c5 {I still don't see a reason for not taking the b-pawn or playing Rf1.} dxc5
```

Comment: Could add that 16 Qd1 is a strange move without any obvious reason. Could think of playing 16. fxg6 instead which also attacks the knight on f6. Besides 16. Nxd4 exd4 17. Qxd4 was still possible.

Comment: Also 24.Rd1 was much better than 24.Resigns, assuming the OP was playing White.

Comment: My computer says that 24.Rd1 Nd7 25.Rf1 is winning for White, and I have to agree with it, but I'm just a patzer.

Answer (score 1):

- 5.h3 is just bad and unnecessary at the time. 5.d5 is to the point.
- 6...exd4 or 6... Nxd4 is direct and obvious.
- 7.d5 again
- 7...Nxd4 again
- 8.d5 Nd4 9.Qd3 is asking to be played again. 8.f5 is the wrong pawn push.
- 11. Bg5 or 11.Nc3 are both better and developing moves.
- 13.Ba4 c6 14.Nd5 is a nice tweener.
- 13...Nxb5 14.cxb5 Qxb5 and your compensation is hard to find.
- you should trade on d4: 14. Nxd4 exd4 15.Qxd4 followed by 0-0 and Bf4 is so much better and direct.
- after your move 14.a4, black should trade Nxb3 (a knight not long for this word for White's good bishop) and snap Nxe4. At this point, White is busted.
- again, 15 Nxd4 is screaming at you. You must end this love affair with the Nb5.
- 15...Nxb3 again. Black should have played this move at any point in the next few moves.
- 16.Qd1 is ... weird. You need to justify that move here with your thinking process. I can't find a reason to play that move. It does not cover any square the queen already covers on d3, and in fact, leave the e-pawn unguarded. Why you do not play Nxd4 is ... uncertain. 
  18...Bxc1 19.Rxc1 a6 wins for black. The care and feeding of your pieces has gone unattended.

So, black opens lines against his king for you and you resign. Clearly after Rd1 white has the edge. 24.Rd1 Ne8 25.Rf1 Qg5 16.Rxf7+ +-.

Lots of tactical oversights that are definitely fixable and should have been seen.

If you are looking for advice it would be stop playing the kings gambit. You are insufficiently skilled in tactics to play such an opening, based on this game. Of course, you can take your lumps and keep playing it. It is just a game.